# Symfony Type error for instance of ArrayCollection instead of instance of Entity

Tags: symfony, typeerror, instanceof, arraycollection

I constantly get the error message:
 *Type error: Argument 2 passed to DocumentBundle\Form\SelectionType::DocumentBundle\Form{closure}() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Channel1 or null, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in /srv/http/sp/src/DocumentBundle/Form/SelectionType.php on line 91*

but I don't yet see where my mistake is. I'm new to php & symfony, so excuse my unknowledge. 
Here is the FormType code, where the error occurs:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
$builder
    ->add('channel1s', EntityType::class, array(
      // 'data' => $channel1s,
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Channel1',
      'property' => 'name',
      'label' => 'label.channel1s',
      'empty_value' => 'label.select_channel1s',
      'mapped' => false,
      'expanded' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
      'multiple' => true,
      'required' => false,
    ));
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Channel1 $channel1s = null) {
      $channel3s = null === $channel1s ? array() : $channel1s->getChannel3s();
      $form
      ->add('channel3s', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Channel3',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'label.channel3s',
        'empty_value' => 'label.select_channel3s',
        'mapped' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
        'multiple' => true,

      ));
    };
  $builder->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getChannel1s());
      }
    );

    $builder->get('channel1s')->addEventListener(
      FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
      function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $channel1s = $event->getForm()->getData();
        dump($channel1s);
        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $channel1s);
      }
      );
}
```

And here are my entities: (I'm trying to create a form to upload Documents called "uploadprofiles" and I'm not exactly sure which one of the entities you need to see for being able to help me)
Uploadprofile looks like that (only some parts):

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Channel1", inversedBy="uploadProfiles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_uploadprofile_channel1s",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="uploadprofile_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel1_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Channel1
     **/
    private $channel1s;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Channel3", inversedBy="uploadProfiles", cascade={"persist"})
         *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_uploadprofile_channel3s",
         *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="uploadprofile_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel3_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
         * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Channel3
         **/
    private $channel3s;
  /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->agencies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->channel3s = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->channel1s = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->locked = false;
        $this->archived = false;
    }
```

and then the Getters, Setters, 'Adders' and 'Removers' for these two.

Does anybody see the mistake or needs more info in order to help me out?

Comment: As error says, you are instantiating a new arrayCollection instead of Channel1 Entity. Try to remove the @var... Regards

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tip! But the same error keeps popping up :/

Comment: Why `'mapped' => false`?

Comment: your're right, I deleted that. But the error doesn't vanish because of that

Comment: no one else any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
'expanded' => true
```

Comment: Ye you have to design the view... 'expanded' => false is for a ManyToOne relation. You have ManyToMany. Don't miss-understand, the FormType is about data, not design

Comment: Ok, I see.. but I have a ajax function for updating the data and that's not working anymore..

Comment: You probably sended the select data. Now you need to send the checked ones, as an array

Comment: I don't know your code, try something with `$( "input:checked" )` .